# Error in pom.xml: Element docker is not allowed here

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64849028/maven-spring-boot-cannot-push-docker-image) and [these instructions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.0/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image-example-publish), I get the error in pom: *Element **docker** is not allowed here*.

EDIT: The complete [pom](https://pastebin.com/bDZrrws3)

Any thoughts about what I am missing?

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>build-image</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <image>
            <name>docker.example.com/library/${project.artifactId}</name>
            <publish>true</publish>
        </image>
        <docker>
            <publishRegistry>
                <username>user</username>
                <password>secret</password>
                <url>https://docker.example.com/v1/</url>
                <email>user@example.com</email>
            </publishRegistry>
        </docker>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Could you add the entire pom?

Comment: What's your spring-boot version?

Comment: I am using: 2.3.7.RELEASE

Comment: That was the problem, I need a superior version of spring-boot!

Comment: The publishRegistry and docker tags appear in version 2.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I check the documentation that you mention and this option is available in version > 2.4.x of Spring that is the reason for your project's failure. If you update the parent-pom to > 2.4.x this will works.

I run this command **mvn spring-boot:build-image**

```
[INFO]     [creator]     *** Images (4a75f3011ab0):
[INFO]     [creator]           docker.example.com/library/coding-challenge:latest
[INFO]
[INFO] Successfully built image 'docker.example.com/library/coding-challenge:latest'
[INFO]
[INFO]  > Pushing image 'docker.example.com/library/coding-challenge:latest' 100%
```